# How to extract href using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I've been following some tutorials but am still not able to correctly extract the href from an HTML document.

For reference, the full page is here: https://boards.greenhouse.io/jopwell.

```
@html_data = open(company.career_page_url).read
@nokogiri_object = Nokogiri::HTML(@html_data)

number_of_jobs = @nokogiri_object.css('div.opening').length

for i in 0..(number_of_jobs-1)
  
    job_name = @nokogiri_object.css('div.opening')[i].css('a').text
    location = @nokogiri_object.css('.location')[i].text
    # job_link_company_page = @nokogiri_object.css('a')[i]["href"]
    #job_link_company_page = @nokogiri_object.css('div.opening')[i].css('a')["href"]
```

There are a few of the these "opening" divs that I'm iterating through. I'm particularly struggling to get the link for each job posting. I've tried a few different variations but am unable to get it to work.

```
<div class="opening" department_id="4051986002" office_id="4000300002" data-office-4000300002="true" data-department-4051986002="true">
  <a data-mapped="true" href="/jopwell/jobs/4065024002">Account Manager</a>
  <br>
  <span class="location">New York, NY - Remote until further notice</span>
</div>
```

Any advice on how to extract the href for each job?

Comment: If any answer fits your need, consider upvoting it or marking it as a solution

Answer (score 1):

That's a great opportunity to use [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) !

```rb
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(URI::open('https://boards.greenhouse.io/jopwell').read)

doc.xpath('//div[@class="opening"]/a/@href').map(&:value)
```

Et voila !

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code to get all job details including job links. Prepended https://boards.greenhouse.io as the parser gives relative links

```
 html_data = open("https://boards.greenhouse.io/jopwell").read
 document = Nokogiri::HTML(html_data)
 openings = document.css('div.opening')
 openings.each do |opening|
    job = opening.css('a').first
    job_title = job.text
    link = "https://boards.greenhouse.io" + job.attributes["href"].value
    location = opening.css('span').text
 end
```

Answer (score -1):

job_link_company_page = @nokogiri_object.css('div.opening')[i].css('a').first["href"]